# Overlaying text on video with required angle using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to overlay some text on video using ffmpeg. I am able to overlay text by the bellow command.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]transpose=2[anticlockwiserotated];[anticlockwiserotated]drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf: text='Test Text':x=100: y=50: fontsize=36: fontcolor=white:[textapplied];[textapplied]transpose=1" output_video.mp4
```

It is allowing me to overlay horizontally or vertically only.

But I want to append it with some angle like 45 degrees.

For that if I modify the command as

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]rotate=45*PI/180[anticlockwiserotated];[anticlockwiserotated]drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf: text='Test Text':x=100: y=50: fontsize=36: fontcolor=white:[textapplied];[textapplied]rotate=315*PI/180" output_video.mp4
```

By this I am getting overlay video as:

[image]

Because in this first I am rotating video to 45 degrees, appending text and bringing it back to original position. So I am loosing borders.

Please suggest me the best way to overlay text with required angle on video.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic method is to generate text on a blank canvas, then an alpha layer for the text, rotating the result and overlaying that on the main video.

In the command below, `a` should be replaced by the angle. The co-ordinates for the drawtext are used in the overlay instead. Depending on the length of your text, some of it may get clipped if you've rotated it anticlockwise. So check and adjust the Y offset accordingly.

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex 
        "color=black:100x100[c];
         [c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv];
         [ct]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf:
             text='Test Text':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text][alpha];
         [text][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=a:ow=rotw(a):oh=roth(a):c=black@0[txta];
         [mv][txta]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(a))+100':y='min(0,W*sin(a))+50':shortest=1"
      output_video.mp4
```

Comment: It is really useful and another small doubt, can we add bold or italic effects to the text... and is it possible to add text at specific time period. I mean from 10th to 20th second of the video only and remaining video should be without text.

Comment: For selective timing, add `enable='between(t,10,20)'` to drawtext. You can use the Bold or Italic TTF for that style.

Comment: Hi for rotation it seems some where I am doing wrong. Please check this command once "ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -filter_complex "color=black:100x100[c];[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile=../../public/fonts/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf:text='Test Text':fontsize=36:fontcolor=white,split[text][alpha];[text][alpha] alphamerge,rotate=55:ow=rotw(55):oh=roth(55):c=black@0[txta];[mv][txta]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin(55))+100':y='min(0,W*sin(55))+50':shortest=1" output_video.mp4". By this I am almost getting 90 degrees but intention is to get 55 degrees. Please guide me where am doing wrong.

Comment: Angle has to be in radians, so 55 deg = a =  `55*PI/180`

Comment: Can we restrict width and height of drawtext. I mean depending upon width text should come to new line dynamically...

Comment: Hello @Mulvya , Can you please tell how to display multiple text at different time through above command.

Comment: @Gyan how to display different text at different time with above command?

Comment: @gone you would just add another drawtext filter immediately after the first one separated by a comma.

Answer (score 4):

One method is by using ASS or SRT subtitles with the FFmpeg [subtitles](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) or [ass](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#ass) filters.

[image]

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "subtitles=diagonal.ass" output
```

SRT subtitles are much simpler than ASS and don't support rotation, but you can manually add it with the filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "subtitles=diagonal.srt:force_style='Angle=45'" output
```

You can create and style the subtitles with [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/) or manually.