# FFMPEG/libavfilter drawtext scaling without affecting video

Tags: c, ffmpeg

How can I scale drawtext without affecting the input video?

Here's my attempt - this filter is applied in C but is equivalent to -filter_complex in command line.

```
[in]drawtext=text='Test Text': fontcolor=white: fontsize=w/40: x=w/20: y=h*16/18:shadowx=1:shadowy=1,scale=iw/2:ih/3[out]
```

The above does scale text but it also affects video as it's part of the drawtext input.

I tried things like:

```
nullsrc=s=iwxih[ns];
[ns]drawtext=text='Test Text': fontcolor=white: fontsize=w/40: x=w/20: y=h*16/18:shadowx=1:shadowy=1,scale=iw/2:ih/3[text];
[in][text]overlay=0:0[out]
```

But it doesn't seem to like `nullsrc` and it hangs... or I am doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why scale the drawtext instead of using an appropriate `fontsize`?

Comment: For various reasons, I need to adapt text aspect ratio to the video. So I need to be able to control text width and height independently.

Comment: Adapt answer(s) in [Overlaying text on video with required angle using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306321/overlaying-text-on-video-with-required-angle-using-ffmpeg).

Comment: Ooh, yes, thank you. That sounds like what I need!