# Darwtext with roatation in ffmpeg not working. shows 'Error marking filters as finished'

Tags: rotation, android-ffmpeg, drawtext

I am trying to rotate draw text on my video with some rotation angle. it starts editing video but after some time displays error 'Error marking filters as finished'  i am using this library for editing. 'https://github.com/yangjie10930/EpMedia'

Following this question. But it's not working. [Overlaying text on video with required angle using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38306321/overlaying-text-on-video-with-required-angle-using-ffmpeg)

```
public static String addTextWithAngle(String inputPath, String outPutPath, String fontPath, String text, String textColor, float fontSize, int x, int y){

 String a =  "(45*PI/180)"; // Angle has to be in radian for accurate rotation
 String complexCommand = "-i "+inputPath+" -filter_complex color=black:100x100[c];[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile="+fontPath+":text='"+text+"':fontsize="+fontSize+":fontcolor=white,split[text][alpha];[text][alpha]alphamerge,rotate="+a+":ow=rotw("+a+"):oh=roth("+a+"):c=black@0[txta];[mv][txta]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin("+a+"))+100':y='min(0,W*sin("+a+"))+50':shortest=1 " + outPutPath;

 Log.e("checkList", complexCommand);
 return complexCommand;
}
```

Logcat

-i /storage/emulated/0/InstaSave/InstaDownload/6a85eec19604481d549dd1953f049248.mp4 -filter_complex color=black:100x100[c];[c][0]scale2ref[ct][mv];[ct]setsar=1,drawtext=fontfile=/storage/emulated/0/.vidMax/Fonts/Light/Roboto.ttf:text='Adnan':fontsize=49.0:fontcolor=white,split[text][alpha];[text][alpha]alphamerge,rotate=(45*PI/180):ow=rotw((45*PI/180)):oh=roth((45*PI/180)):c=black@0[txta];[mv][txta]overlay=x='min(0,-H*sin((45*PI/180)))+100':y='min(0,W*sin((45*PI/180)))+50':shortest=1 /storage/emulated/0/VidMax/VidMaxVideo2.mp4
2019-05-13 15:49:42.995 22436-22436/com.jbsia_dani.videoeditor E/All: Text Added
2019-05-13 15:50:03.918 22436-23067/com.jbsia_dani.videoeditor E/FFmpeg_EpMedia: Error marking filters as finished

Answer (score 0):

Try remove :shortest=1 and replace (45*PI/180) by a specific number

Comment: Already tried this but not working. And angle must be in radian. Any how but tried only number also but its not working.